# Helixtoolkit UWP TransformManipulator3D

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml, helix-3d-toolkit

I'm trying to move/rotate/scale a model using the TransformManipulator3D control in UWP.

I do get it to work but the camera does not stop moving when I'm manipulating the model. So when I try to move/rotate/scale the model the camera also moves and this behavior causes the actual move/scale/rotate to be very wonky and not at all smooth or what is expected.

What am I missing and how can I get this behavior to stop from happening?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working without having to change mouse gestures for the camera.

I did the following:

```
private void viewer_OnMouse3DDown(object sender, MouseDown3DEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.HitTestResult != null && e.HitTestResult.ModelHit is MeshGeometryModel3D model && GroupModel.Any(x => x == model))
        {
            if(ViewerContext.Selected == model)
            {
                ViewerContext.Selected.PostEffects = null;
                ViewerContext.Selected = null;

                return;
            }

            if(ViewerContext.Selected != null)
            {
                ViewerContext.Selected.PostEffects = null;
            }

            ViewerContext.Selected = model;

            ViewerContext.Selected.PostEffects = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewerContext.Selected.PostEffects) ? "border[color:#00FFDE]" : null;

            return;
        }

        if (e.HitTestResult != null && e.HitTestResult.ModelHit is MeshGeometryModel3D pointer && !GroupModel.Any(x => x == pointer))
        {
            ViewerContext.IsRotationEnabled = false;
            ViewerContext.IsMoveEnabled = false;
            ViewerContext.IsPanEnabled = false;

            return;
        }
    }
```

and

```
private void viewer_OnMouse3DUp(object sender, MouseUp3DEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewerContext.IsRotationEnabled = true;
        ViewerContext.IsMoveEnabled = true;
        ViewerContext.IsPanEnabled = true;
    }
```

The pointer variable checks if the ModelHit is part of the TransformManipulator3D control.

I followed the UWP sample for the PostEffects.

The ViewerContext is the ViewModel holding the Viewport3DX properties to know when the camera can again rotate, move or pan.

The GroupModel holds all the models as MeshGeometryModel3D objects.

The TransformManipulator3D control binds to the Selected property on ViewerContext which is also of type MeshGeometryModel3D.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your camera mouse gesture to a different mouse button.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Lance H. Another solution might be to disable Viewport3DX's "IsRotationEnabled" and "IsPanEnabled" properties when drag starts. I haven't tested yet.

Comment: Is there any event on TransformManipulator3D that captures if the object is being manipulated? This is where one would disable the Viewport3DX properties. I try to just add the Viewport3DX.InputBindings like in the example but I get "Cannot assign text value Pan into property Command of type ICommand" errors. My goal is to click a model and be able to move and rotate it. The Wpf.SharpDX example shows how to do this but I guess with UWP it is different.